# Spyder in anaconda always runs in 3.6

Tags: anaconda, spyder

My spyder in anaconda3 refuses to operate in python 3.6
I've tried 
conda update -n TF spyder

Where TF is my environment name, but it stays in python 3.5.
How can I update this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own question by switching to the root environment